# Predicate format, for a single day, to search Steps Sample Array retrieved from HealthKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, healthkit

I want total daily count of steps from steps data retrieved from HealthKit. The data is in an array and I have tried following search predicates, but, none of them match to the data shown in the healthkit.

I am using a simple Query to get all the data first. Then I want to search the array using predicate.

The predicates I have tried are...

```
NSPredicate *daySearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate>=%@ && startDate<%@ && endDate>=%@ && endDate<%@",historyDate,nextDate,historyDate,nextDate];
```

```
NSPredicate *daySearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate>=%@ && startDate<%@",historyDate,nextDate];
```

```
NSPredicate *daySearchPredicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:historyDate endDate:nextDate options:HKQueryOptionStrictEndDate];
```

```
NSPredicate *daySearchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startDate=%@",historyDate];
```

I want the data in my app to match the Health app data.

Please help. I want Objective C code. I do not understand Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `HKStatisticsCollectionQuery` will be more suitable for your requirement because it supports queries over multiples days with specific interval.
From [HKStatisticsCollectionQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticscollectionquery?language=objc) documentation.

> A query that performs multiple statistics queries over a series of fixed-length time intervals, and returns the results.

Sorry to say, do not have a quick set up to post an `Objective-C` sample code snippet. The above documentation should have one `Objc` example for you. I guess you should not have any issue to convert the following one.

```
let queryDateStart = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: -6), to: Date())!)
let queryDateEnd = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: DateComponents(day: 7), to: queryDateStart)!
let predicate = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: queryDateStart, end: queryDateEnd, options:[])
guard let quantityType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
    return // Step Count not available
}
        
let query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(quantityType: quantityType,
                             quantitySamplePredicate: predicate,
                                             options: .cumulativeSum,
                                          anchorDate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0), // Anchor point is mid night
                                  intervalComponents: DateComponents(day: 1))

query.initialResultsHandler = { query, results, error in
     results?.enumerateStatistics(from: queryDateStart, to: queryDateEnd, with: { (result, stop) in
          let stepCount = Int(result.sumQuantity()!.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
                print("Start: \(result.startDate), end: \(result.endDate) => stepCount: \(stepCount)")
     })
}

HKHealthStore().execute(query)
```

Comment: I am not using statistical query. Instead I am running a simple HKSampleQuery and getting all sample data. my code is majorly written around it. Now I just want to get those samples, the steps count total for which will match the health app- for a given date. Can you give me a predicate which will match the same. For example, how can i include time in predicate. that is 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 for a given date. I thing that should do the job.